# Character set issues in filepath using ruby on XP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows-xp

I'm trying to do a `File.exist?(file)` but my ruby script doesn't find the file because of \, spaces, - and . in the filepath. I'm a beginner in ruby and need some help to fix this.

Comment: Actually, I printed the filepath now and saw that the problem is some danish characters in the filepath which cause this problem. Is there anyway to read these chars in ruby?

Comment: you may be also in wrong path, how do you get this filename ?

Comment: I don't think so. 
I do this: 
file = @my_textbox.get_line_text(0);
print file;

Comment: Anybody? How can I print danish or swedish characters in ruby? like: puts "ÅÄÖ"

Comment: This is bogus that the main topic and answer are practically unrelated. Please update the question so internet search result to this isn't misleading.

Comment: try changing the codepage in windows to utf8

Answer (score 0):

I assume it has to do with your OS, more then with Ruby.

file tèst.rb:

```
puts "Hello"
puts "smørebrød"
```

used in irb:

```
irb(main):001:0> require "tèst.rb"
Hello
smørebrød
```

Ruby can include a file with name tèst.rb just fine.

```
irb(main):005:0> f = File.new("ÅÄÖ.txt")
irb(main):006:0> f.each {|l| p l }
    "\"Hej Verden\"\n"
```

loading a file with your requested characters and printing its lines (`p l`) works just fine.
I am running `ruby 1.8.7` on `Ubuntu Linux`. That is a rather old Ruby.

Comment: I have installed Ruby 1.8.7 and try to do same thing as you in XP. Yeah, it could be my OS. Is there any way to fix this!?

Comment: You could give an ubuntu live CD a try. Or try it in a virtual machine. I am quite confident that you will not see the problems there. It looks like a problem with the OS and its file-system.